# Why Finalize should be put protected?

Tags: c++-cli

Reading [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163681.aspx), I came across that simple example, which is really fitted for me since I making some [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) classes over some native c++ interfaces doing the whole job: (and I do it for the first time)

```
ref class Wrapper {
    Native *pn;
public:
    // resource acquisition is initialization
    Wrapper( int val ) { pn = new Native( val ); } 

    // this will do our disposition of the native memory
    ~Wrapper(){ delete pn; }

    void mfunc();
protected:

    // an explicit Finalize() method—as a failsafe
    !Wrapper() { delete pn; }
};
```

This class corresponds exactly to what I have written so far. Save that I had not implemented the Finalize method. But while wondering about its peculiarity and usage, and before I can grasp it much deeper... I was wondering if it is general use and good habit to put the Finalizer method in protected scope.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The access modifier for a finalizer is essentially ignored as there are special rules for finalizers:

1. They can't be called directly (even from within the class itself).
2. When called by the system, they automatically call their base class finalizers.

Officially, the finalizer is a protected virtual method declared on Object: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.finalize.aspx.  In C# you cannot place an accesibilty modifier on the finalizer.

In C++/cli, you can specify any access modifier, but it is essentially ignored.  That is, making it public or private changes nothing: the special rules are still enforced.

So, I'd say, just continue to make it protected just based on convention.